# fullCalendar today button custom behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I have troubles with [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/). I am using week view(defaultView: 'basicWeek'), and the toolbar buttons 'today', 'prev', 'next'. And when I click 'today' button is clicked calendar navigates back to current week, but date selection doesn't change. I want calendar to navigate to current week and select today date on the calendar. But I am having troubles with redefining 'today' button click event.

Code sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/dv9yiq1CdJxfFTsDg4Yx?p=preview

```
defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
              console.log('select');
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); 
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
```

I want a popup(alert) for today date to appear when I clicked 'today' button in this case.So basicly the button click not only navigate me to current week, but to select current day.

Comment: could you provide some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually listen to the today's button click and then call calendar's select method passing correct arguments.

Try the following code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/62Dx5pVrDDXnwoME5jbU?p=preview

```
calendar.find('.fc-today-button').click(function(){
  var start = new Date();
  start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var end = new Date();
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1);
  end.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  calendar.fullCalendar('select', start, end);
});
```

Comment: I have an angular application and I tried this.

ngOnInit() {
        $('#calendar').find('.fc-today-button').click(function() {
            alert("test");
        });
    }

but it is not firing any event

Comment: In spite of ngOnInit() try to use another angular hook (maybe ngAfterViewChecked() ). It is possible that html is not rendered yet when ngOnInit() is called. And because of that jquery can't find ("#calendar") on the page.

Comment: Thanks it worked. However, I don't know why it is alerting forever. I don't know why

Comment: Hey I still could not solve this problem. When I do this, the event is firing more than 400 times. I tried to to $.unbind however in that case the calendar would not switch case. Do you have any idea why it is firing the events many times?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
this.calendarComponent.calendar.today()
```

or

```
this.calendar.getApi().changeView('resourceTimelineWeek','2022-07-26')
```